# "Missing" files on external USB drive in linux mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, external-hdd

I have a 500 GB USB drive mounted as HPFS/NTFS and while copying files to the drive the copying process suddenly failed. After a unmount, unplug and reboot copying works fine again but files in one folder can't be accessed anymore:

```
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
```

other folders work fine. badblocks found no errors on the external hard disk:

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdd1 > bad-sectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 487653042
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors
```

`mount` reads thats fuseblk is used to  mount the the drive, i.e. ntfs-3g is used.

the last output of `dmesg` reads:

```
[63018.326130] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[63018.384505] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=059b, idProduct=0070
[63018.384508] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[63018.384510] usb 2-1: Product: eGo USB
[63018.384511] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Iomega
[63018.384513] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0300000000006D48
[63018.413770] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[63018.416875] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[63018.425905] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[63018.428713] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[63018.469541] scsi host8: uas
[63018.472788] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[63018.477256] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[63018.482405] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     OEM      Ext Hard Disk    0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[63018.664361] scsi 8:0:0:1: CD-ROM            Virtual  CDROM                 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[63018.664664] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[63018.697536] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 975319088 512-byte logical blocks: (499 GB/465 GiB)
[63018.705474] sr 8:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[63018.705675] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[63018.705797] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[63018.758482] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[63018.758487] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 10 00 00 00
[63018.774133] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Cache data unavailable
[63018.774138] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[63019.025475]  sdc: sdc1
[63019.583520] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: I just posted the last lines of `dmesg` as an edit to my original question

Answer (score 3):

The fail probably left the some half-complete information for that directory on the drive. That is not automatically fixed.

You should at least run a `ntfsfix` on the drive

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/<your_usb_drive>
```

`ntfsfix` comes with the package `ntfs-3g` (install with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`)

Comment: Thanks Anthon.  
`ntfsfix worked, sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1  
Mounting volume... OK  
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.  
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK  
NTFS volume version is 3.1.  
NTFS partition /dev/sdd1 was processed successfully`  
  
however, the problem persist, I still get  
 `ls: reading directory .: Input/output error`   
on the folder in question

Comment: I don't use NTFS that much anymore, I would mount the USB drive in a Windows VM (or directly on a Windows machine if you have one), the run a filesystem check there. And if that doesn't work restart from scratch (ie. formatting, assuming you first copy from the USB drive any data for which you have no copy locally).

Comment: @Yar, I agree with @Anthon - `dmesg` does not show hardware disk errors so cause for I/O errors is most probably corrupted filesystem. And NTFS checking tools are in infancy on GNU/Linux... Check the disk in windows machine.